# How to get localized Windows Administrators group name in Inno Setup?

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation, sql-server-express, inno-setup

I need to install SQL Server 2008 using Inno Setup. It requires `/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS` to be specified. I want to set it to `BUILTIN\Administrators`, but the problem is that in localized Windows versions this group's name is different. For example, in Russian version of Windows it's `BUILTIN\Администраторы`.

How can I get the string name for this group (S-1-5-32-544) in Inno Setup?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the name from a SID using [LookupAccountSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379166%28VS.85%29.aspx) API Call.